# Generalizing an expected increase in autocorrelation near a bifurcation point to a system of ODE

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, st.statistics

Near a bifurcation point, a stochastically forced dynamical system should show an increase in autocorrelation and variance.  This is due to critical slowing (a loss in resilience to perturbations).  [See this paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v461/n7260/full/nature08227.html) for an explanation of why this is so.  See Box 3.

I would really like to extend the argument the author presents to a general case.  Let $\mathbf{x}(t) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be the solution to

$$\mathbf{x}'(t) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) \>.$$

The prime here indicates a derivative with respect to time.  Following similar arguments, a vector valued autoregressive model can be constructed for $\mathbf{x}(t)$.  Let $\mathbf{x}^*$ be an equilibrium point and let $\mathbf{D_F}(\mathbf{x}^*)$ be the Jacobian evaluated at the equilibrium.  Then, the repeated disturbances can be expressed like

$$ \mathbf{x}_{n+1} - \mathbf{x}^*
 =
 e^{\mathbf{D_F}(\mathbf{x}^*)}( \mathbf{x}_{n+1} - \mathbf{x}^*) 
 + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_n$$

Where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},I^{n \times n})$.  I would like to show that when the real part of at least one eigenvalue approaches zero from below,then an increase in autocorrelation and variance should be observed.

My current attempt was to transform $ e^{\mathbf{D_F}(\mathbf{x}^*)}$ into a diagonal matrix of complex exponentials

$$ \mathbf{z}_{n+1} = \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 e^{\lambda_1\Delta t} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
 0 & e^{\lambda_2\Delta t} & \dots & 0 \\ 
 \vdots & \dots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
 0 & 0 & \dots & e^{\lambda_n \Delta t}
 \end{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{z}_n + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_n$$

Then it seems that every component is an autoregressive process.  Thus, we can appeal to the author's arguments for why we should expect an increase in the aforementioned stats.  However, that would mean that the autocorrelation $\alpha = e^{\lambda_j \Delta t}$ would be complex valued.  I'm not sure how to show that $\alpha$ should increase as the real part of an eigenvalue approaches zero from below.  Maybe my approach is flawed.

Thoughts are appreciated.